how to pull data from gitlab with php script in laravel?
I create new project in gitlab.
I upload my project in host, I need get last update form gitlab with function in laravel.
My function:
function execPrint($command = "git pull user:pass@gitlab.com/myProject.git") {
    $result = array();
    exec($command, $result);
    print("<pre>");
    foreach ($result as $line) {
        print($line . "\n");
    }
    print("</pre>");
}

After run this function:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname shayvard: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

How to issue this code?

Where does this hostname shayvard come from? Is that something you have defined, is it something github specific, is it related one of the external dependencies of your project, ...?

You used tags [github] and [gitlab]. What is your actual host? Please remove one of the tags. Or both if your actual host is neither one.

@C3roe My project name in gitlab is shayvard. I need update file in host from gitlab.

Are you sure this problem is really related to Laravel or Gitlab? You haven't shared any such code. Also, creating a new project in Gitlab is perfectly possible through their API, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-a-project

The syntax user:pass@gitlab.com/myProject.git for GitLab URL is wrong on all accounts.
First, it's an scp-like syntax for SSH protocol. But you cannot pass user/password to SSH in URL. The user for SSH at GitLab must always be git and authentication is done using keypairs.
To fix your URL: either you switch to HTTPS:
https://user:pat@gitlab.com/user/shayvard.git; please be advised you need a Personal Access Token instead of your account password.
Or you setup an SSH keypair and use one of these syntaxes:
ssh://git@gitlab.com/user/shayvard.git
git@gitlab.com:user/shayvard.git

